# Exploding string by opts with multiple spaces

Tags: php, string, explode

I'm using old PHP4 with Bambalam to make a system for one of my servers to pass some simple data to. But some of the data has spaces in it which doesn't work with how I am iterating settings and I can't quite figure out how to do it. I was told on IRC *not* to use regex which I was told would be slow(?).

This is what I use currently to get my opts from php cmd line, after which I check and only use valid keys.

```
if( $argc == 1 ) {
    print $usage;
    exit;
}

$arguments = array();

while( list($nr, $val) = each($argv) ) {
    if( $nr > 0 ) {
        $val = strtolower($val);
        if ( $val == 'help' ) {
            print $usage;
            exit;
        }
        $arguments[] = explode(' ', trim($val));

    }
}

$settings = array();

foreach ( $arguments as $argument ) {
    $set = explode('=', $argument[0]);
    $settings[str_replace('-','',$set[0])] = $set[1];
}
```

Comment: array_filter can be used to get rid of empty values after your explode.  Which part specifically are you having issues with?  And no, regular expressions, while slower than string comparisons, are not noticeably slow.

Comment: can you show some example value so that we can understand what's going on? also your expected outcome too

Comment: What is IRC? `\h+` should work fine for splitting at every horizontal space, treating multiples as one. https://eval.in/540591

Comment: Imagine a command like this `sender -h=localhost -p=1350 -m=Memory is getting low!` so i'm trying to still split by opts, but get multiple characters string including whitespace. Since this is PHP4, I don't have access to `getopt()`

Comment: Or another [example](http://mrthumb.wasworks.cf/) that isn't too important but this class I imported can't handle folders with spaces in their name as well

Comment: @WAS, getopt() was enabled in PHP 4.3 (released 2002), what version of PHP4 are you on?

Comment: The runtime uses PHP 4.4.4 but `getopt()` is a invalid function in [Bambalam](http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/#whatis)

Comment: Not sure why Bambalam claims PHP 4.4.4 when it's missing a lot of it's features.

Comment: Anything? I still can't seem to think of a way.